# How to replace phtml files in Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.0 admin panel (Store>Cofiguration>Developer>Debug) I have set "Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront" to "Yes". That provides me with references to the phtml files that generates the HTML code for each section.

Q1) Making changes in these files gives the result I am after. But I figure they will be restored/changed if I decide to update Magento to a newer version. Am I right?

Q2) Is there a way to change the phtml files in another way placing the phtml files in my theme folder? If so, where do I place them?

(I am no big fan of XML for simple HTML changes, if possible I would like to write static HTML as much as possible. I have activated my own theme without any base theme. I am new to Magento.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are two ways to change phtml templates. Making changes to original
Magento files is bad practise and should be avoided.

## Custom Theme

Inside a custom theme you can change any template you like, following the folder hierachy of Magento2.
E.g. changing the login.phtml (coming from the module Magento_Customer) your filepath would look like this:

`app/design/frontend/${VENDORNAME}/${THEMENAME}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml`

Source file is living in:

`app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml`

I hope this helps to understand the naming scheme here.

## Custom Module

Inside a custom module it is a little bit harder to change templates. Here is an example of changing topmenu.html coming from
the module Magento_Theme. In your module the template needs to be placed here:

`app/code/${VENDORNAME}/${MODULENAME}/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`

Additionally, a layout definition is required:

`app/code/${VENDORNAME}/${MODULENAME}/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="${VENDORNAME}_${MODULENAME}::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="false"/>
  </body>
</page>
```

Have a look at `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` for reference, where this xml crap can be found ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that out for me!!! I think I see the logic. My path hints gives me for example "/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/bugreport.phtml" (I believe it's "vendor/..." because I downloaded and installed it from Magento.com). I replace "vendor/magento/module-XXX" with "app/design/frontend/YOURVENDORNAME/YOURTHEMENAME/Magento_XXX/" and remove "view/frontend/" from the adress which from the example gives me "app/design/frontend/YOURVENDORNAME/YOURTHEMENAME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/bugreport.phtml".

Comment: For removing the footer links I think you have to edit the XML. See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93628/magento-2-remove-and-change-footer-links

Comment: Does this mean , there are 2 ways of overriding the core phtml files ? and the preferred one is using the Theme inheritence...If we keep our custom phtml file  in theme folder, no need of templates in view/frontend? And what about layout files?